# Calendar in Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I looking to create a custom calender with Zend Framework, I am hoping that it will be able to list all the days of the month for the coming years and then have a different bg color on the date if there is an event on this.  I am however struggling to create this firstly because it needs to go into the layout view, rather than an action, so where does the logic go? I am also unclear as to how the logic with mkdate() would work.

Can someone point me in the right direct please?

Thanks

Comment: It it just for a view or do are you looking for the logic behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple Calendar class that uses Zend_Date and Zend_Locale that you can use as a starting point:

[www.arietis-software.com/index.php/2009/05/26/a-php-calendar-class-based-on-zend_date/](http://www.arietis-software.com/index.php/2009/05/26/a-php-calendar-class-based-on-zend_date/)

Answer (score 1):

I've created and embedded a calendar in a similar why to which you are describing.  My approach was to implement the calendar as a [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom).

The helper, was called `My_View_Helper_Calendar` and has to contain a public method called `calendar` which I have returning an instance of the helper, like so:

```
public function calendar()
{
    // Calls to private methods here
    return $this;
}
```

As indicated, I set up some private methods within the view helper to do the calendar building, and had another public method called `toHtml` which renders the calendar as HTML.

That way, calling the helper from the context of a view file is as easy as:

```
<?= $this->calendar()->toHtml(); ?>
```

Hope this helps you get on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem so I created a calendar for the Zend Framework. It uses Zend_Date and Zend_Locale as well as a view script for rendering. More info can be found at http://www.spiffyjr.me