# How to create a calendar which is getting its data from 4-5 different rss feeds

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

How should I create a calendar for a website, which is getting its data from 4-5 different rss feeds.

I want to use php to do this.

I was thinking google calendars would be the solution, if you too think that, can you plz direct me to a good google calendar tutorial, where I can learn how to embed a google calendar into a website.

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: Google has their own tutorial in their help section...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much interaction you want. The basic idea could be [this](http://www.ducttapemarketing.com/blog/2007/03/17/a-google-calendar-list-of-events-feed-on-your-web-site/).
Then you could embed the calendar like described [here](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=41207)

Or if you want a more privacy concerned version you could make your own by starting with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777206/calendar-in-zend-framework).